# C# Regex replace phrase within text paragraph

Tags: c#, regex

I have a paragraph of text read from a file using C# File.ReadAllText(). Say this was my output:

```
See [a car] is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation 
and a product of the automotive industry. 

Most definitions of the term specify that [a car] is designed to run 
primarily on roads, to have seating for one to eight people, to typically 
have four wheels with tyres
```

I want to match and replace the phrase "a car" but only the SECOND occurrence with "test string". Brackets [ ] added for easier reading but they are not really present within the file text. The regexes I've seen on StackOverflow only replace a character/word within a string that has no line breaks. How can I search an entire paragraph of text and do a regex replace on the second occurrence of a phrase?

Comment: Unless you use `RegexOptions.MultiLine` there is no concept of "line" in Regex. A single `string` is a single `string`. end of lines (`\r\n` or `\n`) are simply "spaces" (in the `\s` meaning)

Comment: Simple solution: `var rx = new Regex(Regex.Escape("[a car]")); int found = 0; string text2 = rx.Replace(text, x => found++ == 1 ? "[Some Replace Text]" : x.Value);`

Comment: @xanatos Simple and elegant solution, thanks!